# Am charts v3 XY not working with logarithmic scale

Tags: javascript, charts, amcharts, logarithm

I'm woking with angularJS and npm package amcharts3 "^3.21.15". I'm having a little issue with logarithmic scale in my XY chart. This is my chart without logarithmic scale:

[Working Chart without logarithmic scale](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kNRse.png)

ValueAxes code:

```
"valueAxes": [{
          //"logarithmic": true,
          "minMaxMultiplier": 1.2,
          "position": "bottom",
          "axisAlpha": 0,
          "title": "Grupos"
        }, {
          //"logarithmic": true,
          "minMaxMultiplier": 1.2,
          "axisAlpha": 0,
          "position": "left"
          }
        ]
```

When I activate both log scale, the chart just get blank:

[Not working blank chart](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ey2IH.png)

And when I activate only one scale (X or Y), the chart still not showing the data, only the respective axes lines and values:

[Not working chart showing only one axes information](https://i.stack.imgur.com/39mxc.png)

And there's no error in browser console.

Could someone help me, please?

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Logarithimic scale only supports positive, non-zero values and will break if you have data that doesn't meet this condition, which your working chart screenshot seems to show. For zero values, you can use the [`treatZeroAs`](https://www.amcharts.com/docs/v3/reference/valueaxis/#treatZeroAs_property) property to remap those values to a small decimal value; negative values need to be removed:

```
"valueAxes": [{
 "logarithmic": true,
 "treatZeroAs": 0.01,
 "minMaxMultiplier": 1.2,
 "position": "bottom",
 "axisAlpha": 0,
 "title": "Grupos"
}, {
 "logarithmic": true,
 "treatZeroAs": 0.001
 "minMaxMultiplier": 1.2,
 "axisAlpha": 0,
 "position": "left"
 }
]
```